# c++ memory order in RocksDB source code void WriteThread::SetState(Writer* w, uint8_t new_state)

Tags: c++, rocksdb

I've been reading through the source code of rocksdb lately, but I've run into a problem I can't figure out and would like to ask for advice

```cpp
void WriteThread::SetState(Writer* w, uint8_t new_state) {
  assert(w);
  auto state = w->state.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
  if (state == STATE_LOCKED_WAITING ||
      !w->state.compare_exchange_strong(state, new_state)) {
    assert(state == STATE_LOCKED_WAITING);

    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(w->StateMutex());
    assert(w->state.load(std::memory_order_relaxed) != new_state);
    w->state.store(new_state, std::memory_order_relaxed);
    w->StateCV().notify_one();
  }
}
```

For code `auto state = w->state.load(std::memory_order_acquire);`
my first question:
Why not use memory_order_relaxed, because for `if (state == STATE_LOCKED_WAITING` ... The included blocks are dependent on the variable state and are not supposed to be rearranged before the `w->state.load` code, so there is no need to use `std::memory_order_acquire`.

my second question:
For code segments

```cpp
std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(w->StateMutex());
assert(w->state.load(std::memory_order_relaxed) != new_state);
w->state.store(new_state, std::memory_order_relaxed);
w->StateCV().notify_one();
```

Can it be written as follows？

```cpp
assert(w->state.load(std::memory_order_relaxed) != new_state);
w->state.store(new_state, std::memory_order_relaxed);
std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(w->StateMutex());
w->StateCV().notify_one();
```

I'm not sure why we need to lock mutex here, I think `w->state.store` has already got the latest value, there must be something wrong with my understanding, I hope you can correct me!

I'm learning memory order in c++, and I don't know if the above is correct, guys, can you give me the right answer?

Answer (score 0):

*Can it be written as follows?* It can't be answered "Yes" without seeing the other code, that waits for `w->StateCV()` or uses `w->state`. Thus, the answer is No, it can't. If it's rewritten as shown, it breaks the original function logic.

1. `w->state` in the new code can be changed between `assert()` and `store()`.
2. `w->state` in the new code can be changed between `store()` and `notify_one()`.